# I can not train a logical operation xor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I can not train the network (keras + tf) of the simplest logical operation xor. I can not understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
VALIDATION_SPLIT=0.1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='random_normal', 
use_bias=True,
            bias_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Dense(1, use_bias=True, bias_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary() # print information about structure of neural net
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01),    
              metrics= ['accuracy']) #mean_squared_error

X_train = np.array([ [0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1] ])
Y_train = np.array([ [0],[1],[1],[0] ])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
                batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=1, 
validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)
print(model.predict(np.array([[0,1]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[1,0]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[1,1]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[0,0]])))

results:
[[ 1.]]
[[ 1.]]
[[ 1.]]
[[ 1.]]
```

Comment: Can you specify the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: the above code does not work, although it seems to me that everything should work, the problem is in training - the network is not trained and produces incorrect results

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems:

- Softmax always outputs a sum of 1. It's natural that your output will always be 1 then.
- Validation split is using data that should be for training
- Too few epochs, you will need thousands of epochs for that.

After fixing this, then you should think about whether your chosen network is capable of doing this.

This model was able to learn:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='random_normal', 
            use_bias=True, bias_initializer='random_normal', activation ='softplus'))
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='random_normal', 
            use_bias=True, bias_initializer='random_normal', activation ='softplus'))

model.add(Dense(1, use_bias=True, bias_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Your model is also possible, but needs some tweaks:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation ='softplus'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary() # print information about structure of neural net
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',    
              metrics= ['accuracy']) #mean_squared_error

X_train = np.array([ [0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1] ])
Y_train = np.array([ [0],[1],[1],[0] ])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
                batch_size=1, epochs=10000, verbose=1)

print(model.predict(X_train))
```

Comment: If you think this answered your question, please mark it as answered :)